# Strange output for keras regression model

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, keras, regression

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qxo8.png)

I just started to make regression model in Keras. I tried on my own photos, but I got loss as `Nan` and accuracy zero as output. Can anyone explain why?

```
data=pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx',sheet_name=2)
data.head(2)
features=data.drop('PRHP',axis=1)
labels=data['PRHP']
# Normalizing data:
m_features=features.mean(axis=0)
m_labels=labels.mean(axis=0)
std_features=features.std(axis=0)
std_labels=labels.std(axis=0)
nor_features=(features-m_features)/std_features
nor_labels=(labels-m_labels)/std_labels
# Build Model:
model=Sequential([Dense(12,input_shape=(7,),activation='linear'),Dense(1,activation='linear')])
model.summary()
model.compile(adam(lr=0.01),loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(nor_features,nor_labels, batch_size=10, epochs=10, shuffle=True,verbose=2)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
 - 0s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
 - 0s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
 - 0s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
 - 0s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reason for a `nan` loss is the existence of `nan` values in the training data itself. If there is any `nan` values in the original data try to fill them with some value or entirely remove their corresponding row sample. Otherwise, if there is no missing data in the original data, since you are normalizing by dividing by std, it might be that the value of std is zero and therefore causes division by zero. To prevent this, add a small constant when performing division:

```
nor_features = (features-m_features) / (std_features + 1e-7)
nor_labels = (labels-m_labels) / (std_labels + 1e-7)
```

As for the accuracy being zero, you must keep in mind that the `'accuracy'` metric in Keras is only used for classification problems. Here, since you are doing regression it does not make sense at all to use `'accuracy'` as the metric. Instead, you can use other metrics like `mae` (i.e. mean absolute error) or don't use any metric at all.

Comment: much appreciated, i adhered to notes, checked Nan values, dropped two rows with Nan values, but still getting Nan. finally when i added constant to std started to get results  (even std values don't have zero, least value is 0.579207)